# Net Present Value in Excel for Grouped Recurring CF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below is a cash flow table for 60 periods.

There is a set of recurring cash flows.  Is there a simple way in excel to calculate the NPV for all 60 periods (monthly cashflows) without have to create a table of 60 rows and using the NPV formula?

So the formula for 60 line items would be something like this:

`=NPV(PERIODIC RATE, VALUES OF CF 1 - 60) + CF0`

But can you shortcut it if you know there are recurring cashflows in excel and not have to enumerate all 60 rows?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function that will do this, but we can build our own.  This is a UDF(User Defined Function):

```
Function myNPV(rate As Double, vl As Range, times As Range)
If vl.Cells.Count <> times.Cells.Count Then Exit Function
Dim vlArr() As Variant
Dim timesArr() As Variant
Dim ovlArr() As Double
Dim i&, j&, t&, cnt&

vlArr = vl.Value
timesArr = times.Value
For i = LBound(vlArr, 1) To UBound(vlArr, 1)
    If vlArr(i, 1) <> "" Then
        t = t + timesArr(i, 1)
    End If
Next i
cnt = 1
ReDim ovlArr(1 To t)
For i = LBound(vlArr, 1) To UBound(vlArr, 1)
    If vlArr(i, 1) <> "" Then
        For j = 1 To timesArr(i, 1)
            ovlArr(cnt) = vlArr(i, 1)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next j
    End If
Next i

myNPV = Application.WorksheetFunction.NPV(rate, ovlArr)

End Function
```

In the workbook hit Alt-F11.  This will open the VBE.

Go to Insert and insert a module.  This will open a new module.  Copy and paste the code above.

The you can call it like any other formula:

```
=myNPV(C20/C19,B3:B17,C3:C17)+B2
```

This has three criteria: The rate per, amounts range, and corresponding number of times.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an annuity formula

In `D1` use `=1/($B$7/12)*(1-1/(1+$B$7/12)^C1)*B1*1/(1+$B$7/12)^(SUM($C$1:C1)-12)` and copy down

[image]

Comment: thanks. can you type out the finance formula you used with variables and explain and give financial background?