# How to perform column to row operations in excel

Tags: excel

[image]

Check out the selection in the top right, columns "Purchase/Sale" and "NOI".

I'd like to add these two columns and insert the sum for each period in their respective space.  Is there I can link the sum of the columns and add the sum to the row?

In other words, I'd like the cells to link so I would have the following result:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array form of VLOOKUP wrapped in SUM():

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP("CF" & G1,$A$2:$C$7,{2,3},FALSE))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. I'm familiar with vlookup. Can you explain the first argument "CF" & G1.

Comment: Since in your first picture you have `CF0,CF1` but in your second you are using only the number portion to indicate to which row it should be linked, I simply add it in the formula.  So since G1 in `0` I add the `CF` to the front so the vlookup is now looking in column A for `CF0` which it finds in A2.  It is a concatenation of two strings to make them one string.  That way as the formula is copied across it changes from `CF0` to `CF1`

Comment: Did you ever get a satisfactory answer for your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359503/net-present-value-in-excel-for-grouped-recurring-cf ?

Comment: Thanks I understand your answer. I did not get a satisfactory answer for my other question. BretDJ posted an answer that seems to solve my question but I do not understand his annuity formula.